# Keep both in git conflict during rebase

Tags: git

Simple line additions seem to create a merge conflict when rebasing. Is there a way or strategy that can be applied that will allow me to take both?

Comment: Can you give more details? Show us the files where conflicts happened and what would be your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the file that has conflicts.

`Git` tells you where conflicts are, so if you want to keep both versions (`head` and `commit` changes), you can edit the file (merging conflicts manually) and then stage it (with `git add`). Finally you use `git rebase --continue`, to continue with your `rebase`.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a merge strategy that just takes both. This is just describing normal procedure!